# How to pass parameters to batch file in javascript code

Tags: javascript, shell, batch-file

I am having problems passing parameters into a batch file in javascript code.

The js file is below:

```
var url1 = $scope.data.url;
var user1 = $scope.data.user;
var password1 = $scope.data.password;

MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
MyObject.Run("C:/Users/AAA/Desktop/cmd.bat [url1] [user1] [password1]");
```

And bat file:

```
@echo off

:: Fetch param1
set "param1=%~1"
goto :param1Check
:param1Prompt
set /p "param1=Enter parameter 1: "
:param1Check
if "%param1%"=="" goto :param1Prompt

:: Fetch param2    
set "param2=%~2"
goto :param2Check
:param2Prompt
set /p "param2=Enter parameter 2: "
:param2Check
if "%param2%"=="" goto :param2Prompt

:: Fetch param3    
set "param3=%~3"
goto :param2Check
:param3Prompt
set /p "param3=Enter parameter 3: "
:param2Check
if "%param3%"=="" goto :param3Prompt
```

---

```
C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\dirb18_win\wordlists\diran.txt -o C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\AutomateTool\filewindows.txt -url "%param1% -u "%param2%:%param3%"  -w -i
```

It's taking parameters as it is means [url1] [user1] [password1]

Please help me out

Comment: You should try string concatenation.

Comment: `MyObject.Run('C:/Users/AAA/Desktop/cmd.bat "' + url1 + '" "' + user1 + '" "' + password1 + '"');` or something alike?

Comment: Thank You, Its working fine